# Is it possible to access this room in Hateno Village?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

This house in Hateno Village:

[image: house]

has a visible niche on the left with a couple of little windows, but inside the house there is no visible access to it. Also, inside the house there is a mezzanine which works as the upper floor, but the corresponding ground floor part is inaccessible.

Notice that:

> I know this house can be bought and furnished, but doing so does not (apparently) change the accessibility of these spaces.

Is there any way to access these parts of the house or at least see if there's anything inside them?

Comment: From personal experience just playing the game I've found no way to access these areas but I have no factual proof to back up those claims.  These areas may be accessible via glitching or something along those lines but I would then expect them to be completely empty or non-existent.

Comment: Thank you @BlueBarren for the comment. This is also what I thought at first, but playing the game more thoroughly I came across many "unlikely"  and surprising events (like the one in the spoiler quote) and I'm not excluding a secret (or maybe future) access to those rooms. I also tried to glitch into them, unsuccessfully, but I'll accept answers giving glitches as proof of room emptiness/secrecy.

Comment: You've also got a shed you can't even open. My assumption is that this is just down to modular assets not lining up correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Although there is not a definitive answer from a Nintendo dev (which is probably the only way to get *definitive* proof), there has been a plethora of other players asking this question, and the consensus is **no, it is not possible to enter this room**, or any of the other small "outhouses" attached to buildings that don't have interactable doors/openings.

Here are a few conversations from other players confirming this theory...

1. From [BOTW Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Breath_of_the_Wild/comments/624iox/playerowned_house_shed/):

> If you pay attention you will see that there is a few rooms like that
>   one in the village and none opens. I guess its just cosmetic, at least
>   for now. Maybe they had to cut down rooms because the Wii U couldnt
>   handle so much stuff in the village.
>
> I believe they're outhouses.
>   Of all the things Nintendo had to put in the game, I think they
>   decided to skimp a bit in certain areas.

2. From a [GameFAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/632936-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75865886), which also confirmed lack of entry.
3. From another [GameFAQs thread](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/boards/189707-the-legend-of-zelda-breath-of-the-wild/75751372), where multiple players explicitly indicate the lack of ability to enter "Link's shack":

> There's also a "storage shed" kind of addition on the back of the
>   house - WITH A DOOR - that you can't open and get into ...

Comment: Of course, you can always use the [normal quest](https://www.polygon.com/zelda-breath-of-the-wild-guide-walkthrough/2017/3/30/15129382/hylian-homeowner-side-quest-why-buy-a-house-cost-rupees-characters-bolson-requirements-location) to get into the main room of the house, but I figured you already knew that.